# What happens when declaring a variable?

Tags: python, c

when I read this article about Python and Computer memory which is:

> Variables are a way to keep track of values stored in computer
>   memory. A variable is a named location in computer memory. Python
>   keeps variables in a separate list from values. A variable will
>   contain a memory address, and that memory address contains the value.
>   The variable then refers to the value. Python will pick the memory
>   addresses for you.
>
> ```
> Terminology
>
> A value has a memory address.
> A variable contains a memory address.
> A variable refers to a value.
> A variable points to a value.
> Example: Value 8.5 has memory address id34.
> Variable shoe_size contains memory address id34.
> The value of shoe_size is 8.5.
> shoe_size refers to value 8.5.
> shoe_size points to value 8.5.
> ```

My first question is: Does this mean that when I make a variable `x` for example, a memory location is reserved for its value and another memory location is reserved for its memory address?!

My second question is: Does this rule applied on C programming language?!

Comment: No, there is no memory allocated for symbol. After compiled, there are just all kinds of addresses in your program.

Comment: No, and no. As your text says, Python keeps variables separate from *values*. The C analogy would be pointers (as variables) and dynamically allocated memory (as values).

Comment: can you clarify your comment in answer please @KerrekSB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in Python are "referential", in the sense that they aren't themselves values, but *refer* to a value. The values themselves are immutable, and stored separately. If you "assign" a variable, what in fact happens is that the value is looked up (possibly created), and a *reference* to that value is assigned to the variable.

If you were to handle variables like that in C, you would use pointers a lot. For example, an "integer variable `x`" to which you assign different values would go like this:

```
int * make_int(int val)
{
    int * p = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p = val;
    return p;
}

int * x = make_int(5);      // Python: x = 5   # x is a new variable

x = make_int(7);            //         x = 7

x = make_int(11);           //         x = 11
```

The difference is that the above C code leaks memory at every step, while in Python the memory would be managed somehow, and for example if the requested value already had a matching allocation, you'd just get a pointer to that rather than creating a new object. In other words, there's only one, unique "5".

Answer (score 2):

> when I make a variable x for example, a memory location is reserved for its value

Yes.

> and another memory location is reserved for its memory address?!

Python internals almost certainly do do that, although since this is a matter of implementation it is irrelevant programatically -- you do not access it directly.  Which brings us to:

> Does this rule applied on C programming language?!

In C, we would call this the relationship between a pointer and a variable:

```
int x;
int *p = &x;
```

Here there is a memory location storing the value in 'x', and another location storing the value in 'p'.  However, the value in p *is the address of the value in x*.

Python is implemented in C and uses dynamic typing, so all your variables are more complex objects ("under the hood") involving pointers and plain values, but again, since you do not access this programmatically in python, it's not very meaningful.  Addresses are accessed and manipulated directly in C code but not in python code (but they are in the C code which implements python).

Comment: What's up with "do do that"? Should that be "do not do that"? It's a bit unclear, or I'd edited it for you.

Comment: @unwind : I meant that *internally* a python variable is not just a value somewhere, but a "more complex" object that includes pointers -- this is an inevitable consequence of dynamic typing.  So python *does* store addresses, just the python programmer does not need to know or care about them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with C, variables in most "modern" languages are very close to pointers in C.

i.e

```
x = 20
```

In python, x refers to a memory location which contains the int(?) object of value 20.

In C++ this would be

```
 int *x = new int(20);
```

This is what you need to understand to work with python. How the memory location, i.e the content of the x variable itself is stored, I am not sure.. in C/C++ they are stored on the stack frame of the current scope, in python apparently they are stored in a dictionary.. (source : Thomas' answer)

Answer (score 0):

In python all variables are stored in dictionaries, so maybe that's where you get the confusion from